# Rails - Convert time to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

This is the time format I want to convert

```
time = Time.parse('2020-07-02 03:59:59.999 UTC')
#=> 2020-07-02 03:59:59 UTC
```

I want to convert to string in this format.

```
"2020-07-02T03:59:59.999Z"
```

I have tried.

```
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.999Z")
```

Is this correct? Any better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`Time#iso8601`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-xmlschema) with the desired number of fraction digits as an argument:

```
time = Time.current.end_of_hour

time.iso8601(3) #=> "2020-07-01T10:59:59.999Z"
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the output format explicitly via [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#strftime-method), there are some things to keep in mind:

Instead of hard-coding `999`, you should use `%L` to get the actual milliseconds:

```
time = Time.parse('2020-07-02 03:59:59.999 UTC')
#=> 2020-07-02 03:59:59 UTC

time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ')
#=> "2020-07-02T03:59:59.999Z"
```

Use combinations for common formats, e.g. `%F` for `%Y-%m-%d` and `%T` for `%H:%M:%S`:

```
time.strftime('%FT%T.%LZ')
#=> "2020-07-02T03:59:59.999Z"
```

If you are dealing with time zones other than UTC (maybe your machine's local time zone), make sure to convert your time instance to [`utc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-i-utc) first:

```
time = Time.parse('2020-07-02 05:59:59.999+02:00')
#=> 2020-07-02 05:59:59 +0200

time.utc
#=> 2020-07-02 03:59:59 UTC

time.strftime('%FT%T.%LZ')
#=> "2020-07-02T03:59:59.999Z"
```

or to use `%z` / `%:z` to append the actual time zone offset:

```
time = Time.parse('2020-07-02 05:59:59.999+02:00')

time.strftime('%FT%T.%L%:z')
#=> "2020-07-02T05:59:59.999+02:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

For APIs you should use `utc.iso8601`:

```rb
> timestamp = Time.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2015-07-04T21:53:23Z"
```

See:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones#working-with-apis